# Performance in Different Ways of Mysql Count

Tags: mysql, concurrency, count

Mysql **count** can be used in different ways. Following are 3 ways that we can use.

1. `SELECT COUNT(table_1.id) FROM <data set with many joints>;`
2. `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT table_1.id FROM <data set with many joints>);`
3. `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT table_1.id,table_1.field_1,table_2.field_2,...,table_n.field_n FROM <data set with many joints>);`

Is there any difference in performance in the queries above? Can someone explain considering concurrency also?

Comment: I don't think any of those queries work. You can't access table names from a subquery.

Comment: And you can't put a subquery inside `COUNT()`.

Comment: Did you mean to use the alias `table_1` for the subquery?

Comment: I suspect they'll all be identical performance. Use `EXPLAIN` to see how the query planner processes them.